# I can not subscribe with ESP8266-ESP32 in IBM Watson IOT

Tags: mqtt, publish-subscribe, esp8266, watson-iot

I want to subscribe to the "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json" topic with ESP8266 on IBM Watson IOT. The connection is established but it is disconnecting again. So, reconnecting the MQTT client to … and subscribe to iot-2 / cmd / + / fmt / + OK. This cycle continues. Why is the connection broken?

My ESP8266 code is as follows.

I used an ESP8266-12E NodeMCU, I’ve created an Android app for the publisher.

```
/*
 Basic ESP8266 MQTT example

 This sketch demonstrates the capabilities of the pubsub library in combination
 with the ESP8266 board/library.

 It connects to an MQTT server then:
  - publishes "hello world" to the topic "outTopic" every two seconds
  - subscribes to the topic "inTopic", printing out any messages
    it receives. NB - it assumes the received payloads are strings not binary
  - If the first character of the topic "inTopic" is an 1, switch ON the ESP Led,
    else switch it off

 It will reconnect to the server if the connection is lost using a blocking
 reconnect function. See the 'mqtt_reconnect_nonblocking' example for how to
 achieve the same result without blocking the main loop.

 To install the ESP8266 board, (using Arduino 1.6.4+):
  - Add the following 3rd party board manager under "File -> Preferences -> Additional Boards Manager URLs":
       http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
  - Open the "Tools -> Board -> Board Manager" and click install for the ESP8266"
  - Select your ESP8266 in "Tools -> Board"

*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
//#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
//ZYxel
#define ssid  "......."
#define password  ".................."

//GES ARGE
#define ssid2     "..............."      // WiFi SSID
#define password2  "............."  // WiFi password

#define spi_ss_pin SS

#define ORG "............"
#define DEVICE_TYPE "........."
#define DEVICE_ID "..........."
#define TOKEN "................"
//-------- Customise the above values --------
char server[] = ORG ".messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com";
int mqttPort=1883;
const char topic[] = "iot-2/cmd/status/fmt/json"; //"iot-2/cmd/status/fmt/json";

char authMethod[] = "use-token-auth";
char token[] = TOKEN;
char clientId[] = "d:" ORG ":" DEVICE_TYPE ":" DEVICE_ID;

WiFiClient wifiClient;
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int payloadLength) ;
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, wifiClient);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  wifiConnect();
  mqttConnect();
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.loop()) {
    mqttConnect();
  }
}

void wifiConnect() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.print(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.print("nWiFi connected, IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void mqttConnect() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Reconnecting MQTT client to "); Serial.println(server);
    while (!client.connect(clientId, authMethod, token)) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(500);
    }
    initManagedDevice();
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void initManagedDevice() {
  if (client.subscribe(topic)) {
    Serial.println("subscribe to cmd OK");
  } else {
    Serial.println("subscribe to cmd FAILED");
  }
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int payloadLength) {
  Serial.print("callback invoked for topic: "); Serial.println(topic);

  for (int i = 0; i < payloadLength; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A device ("use-token-auth" authentication type) cannot subscribe to a topic like "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json" only "iot-2/cmd/status/fmt/json" is allowed.

What you need to do is to generate an API key and token and authenticate as an application:

The following example shows a typical API key:

a-orgId-a84ps90Ajs

The following example shows a typical authentication token:

MP$08VKz!8rXwnR-Q*

When you make an MQTT connection by using an API key, ensure that the following guidelines are applied:

```
The MQTT client ID is in the format: a:orgId:appId
The MQTT user name is the API key (for example, a-orgId-a84ps90Ajs)
The MQTT password is the authentication token (for example, MP$08VKz!8rXwnR-Q*)
```

After that you can subscribe to topic like iot-2/type/device_type/id/device_id/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string. So it should be:

iot-2/type/yourDeviceType/id/yourDeviceId/evt/status/fmt/json

You can use the same for commands: this how the topic should look like
 iot-2/type/device_type/id/device_id/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string

Comment: hi @idan. thanks for answer.   I do not subscribe to the topic by saying "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json". I am publishing it via android by saying "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json". If you examine the above esp8266 codes, I subscribed to the topic by saying there "iot-2/cmd/status/fmt/json". I have applied your suggestion above, but the result is still negative. And in this example, "https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/build-your-own-watson-controlled-kettle/" was not done as you suggested.

Comment: in your post at the beginning you said:
"I want to subscribe to "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json" topic with esp8266 on ibm watson IOT."
Are you able to connect at all? If not, I notice you want to connect over 1883. If you want to do that you need to set the TLS Optional under security settings in IoT Platform. 

If you need to get events on "iot-2/cmd/status/fmt/json" you need to publish on that topic (as an application for e.g) Publishing events on "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json" won't mean you'll be getting them into "iot-2/cmd/status/fmt/json". They are 2 different things.

Comment: I setted TLS as optional under the IOT platform security settings but I couldn't connect. Essentially I want to publish from my android app. and subscribing from ESP8266 module.

Comment: thanks for answer @idan.  I found the solution to the problem. my mistake, the error occurred because I used the same api_key for both applications.